# Regex for uppercase headlines

Tags: php, regex

I'm facing a little problem regarding extracting headline from string by using RegEx in PHP. There is a pattern that all headline (if they are present - there could also be no headline).

**Pattern of the headline**

- it is always on the beginning of the string
- it is always in UPPERCASE (but there could be lowercase letters if there is a dash between two words) ie. (HEADLINEWORD-lowercaseword)
- it can contain Unicode chars

I fould [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308947/php-regex-find-uppercase-string-with-number-and-spaces-in-text) on stackoverflow, but it isn't working for me as it doesn't matches words that have dash between uppercase and lowercase words..

Please help :)

**EDIT**

Here are few examples:

- **VRH SDP-a O SUDBINI MERZEL I SABE** Ostojić: 'Ona je izvanredna županica!'
- **VIDEO: KRVAVI NAPAD NA ŠKOLSKOM HODNIKU** Pomahnitali učenik (16) izbo 20 ljudi: 'Bio je to pravi pakao'
- **REZAT ĆE PLAĆE RADNICIMA I ŠEFOVIMA JAVNIH PODUZEĆA?** Ministar Linić: 'Sve je dogovoreno'

## SOLUTION

I analysed @Jonny5's comment and modified it a little so I ended with this:

```
/^(?:[\p{Lu}\pN]+(?:-[\pL\pN]+)*(?:\s+|$|\?|!|\:))+/u
```

After that @PatrickQ modified it a bit so now the final RegEx looks like this and it matches all examples from this question.

```
/^(?:[\p{Lu}\pN:?]+(?:-[\pL\pN]+)*(?:\s+|$|\?|!|\:))+/u
```

Comment: can you show some examples and what you've tried

Comment: Something [like this](http://regex101.com/r/rQ5gD8) convenient?

Comment: Jonny5, it looks close, but if fails on some of them.. I've added few examples to my original question.

Comment: @suntribe is there always a colon in each and every headline/string? Could use something [like this](http://regex101.com/r/uN6dF6) then better.

Comment: I took your "partial solution" and made a slight change. This seems to work for all 3 of your examples: `/^(?:[\p{Lu}\pN:?]+(?:-[\pL\pN]+)*(?:\s+|$|\?|!|\:))+/u`

Comment: @Jonny5, unfortunatelly no.. Last example you gave also selects part that shouldn't be in headline.. As I said, your first regex was very very close to my needs, I just updated it so it looks for few more punctuation chars at the end and that should be it... except the part that i need to run it twice so it selects VIDEO: and the rest of the uppercase headline after VIDEO part :)

Comment: I see, well, @PatrickQ's mod should be fine then.

Comment: @PatrickQ that's it :) I knew that there should be a little change so it would work as it should.. Thanks guys for help.

p.s. How should I accept the best answer when the problem was solved in comment?

Comment: Up to you :) maybe @PatrickQ puts his comment as an answer, I won't, his was the final working one.

Comment: @Jonny5 did the legwork. So if he's not going to take credit, neither am I.  I do believe that you're allowed to answer your own question, if you want to do that.

Comment: :) As I'm new here, I cannot (I believe that's the reason why I have no checkmark next to my question)..

Comment: Checkmarks appear next to answers, not questions. So you would have to post an answer, and then accept it.

Comment: You see?! I said I'm new here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I analysed @Jonny5's first comment and it's regex and modified it a little so I ended with this:

```
/^(?:[\p{Lu}\pN]+(?:-[\pL\pN]+)*(?:\s+|$|\?|!|\:))+/u
```

After that @PatrickQ modified it a bit so now the final RegEx looks like this and it matches all examples from this question.

```
/^(?:[\p{Lu}\pN:?]+(?:-[\pL\pN]+)*(?:\s+|$|\?|!|\:))+/u
```

Answer (score 0):

So match any ALLCAPS word at the beginning of the string, possibly followed by a dash, and then the word after it.

Try this: `preg_match("/^([A-Z]+[-:\s]?.*[A-Z]+)+/", $input_line, $output_array);`

Validated here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/4KG

Comment: Hi Roberto, it only extracts one (first) word.. I figured that I haven't clearly explained the complexity of the neede regex :) Sorry :)

Comment: So let me try to understand, in the case where a sentence starts with ALLCAPS, you want the entire line? Or just the ALLCAPS word?

Comment: I want all ALLCAPS words that are in sequence... See my original question (I updated it with few examples - I bolded the headlines that I would like to extract)

Comment: Still nothing, your regex doesn't match none of my string I've put in my questio... I came with some kind of solution (I updated my question with it) but it isn't a final one...

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
preg_match('/^((?:\p{Lu}+(?:-\p{Ll}+)?\s+)+)/', $string, $match);
```

`\p{Lu}` stands for any uppercase letter
`\p{Ll}` stands for any lowercase letter